Generalizing a gaussian mix to take any number of arguments with numpy.vectorize causes performance issues
I am optimizing a gaussian mix using maximum likelyhood estimation. Originally I used the following model:
def normal(x, mu, sigma):
    """
    Gaussian (normal) probability density function.
    
    Args:
        x (np.ndarray): Data points.
        mu (float): Mean of the distribution.
        sigma (float): Standard deviation of the distribution.
    
    Returns:
        np.ndarray: Probability density values.
    """
    return (1 / (np.sqrt(2 * np.pi) * sigma)) * np.exp(-0.5 * ((x - mu) / sigma) ** 2)

def model(x, a, mu1, s1, mu2, s2):
    return a*normal(x, mu1, s1) + (1-a)*normal(x, mu2, s2)

This works great and finds a good fit in under a second.
I now wanted to dynamically generate such a function for any number of peaks.
def generate_gaussian_mix(n):
    def gaussian_mix(x, *params):
    
        if len(params) != 3 * n - 1:
            print(params)
            raise ValueError(f"Expected {3 * n - 1} parameters, but got {len(params)}.")

        params = np.asarray(params)
        mu = params[0::3]  # Means
        sigma = params[1::3]  # Standard deviations
        a = params[2::3]  # Weights
        a = np.hstack((a, 1 - np.sum(a)))

        return np.sum((a / (np.sqrt(2 * np.pi) * sigma))*np.exp(-0.5 * ((x - mu) / sigma) ** 2))

    return np.vectorize(gaussian_mix)

This model takes over three minutes to compute on my laptop with the same number of peaks and events. What are optimization steps I could take to reduce the magnitude of this second function? Is there a good way to avoid vectorization? Do you have any ideas to avoid the repeated slicing?
for completeness, this is the optimization function:
def neg_log_event_likelyhood(model, event, theta):
    x = -np.log(model(event, *theta))
    return x

def fit_distribution_anneal(model, events, bounds, data_range = None, **kwargs):
    def total_log_likelyhood(theta, model, events):
        return np.sum(neg_log_event_likelyhood(model, events, theta))

    if data_range is not None:
        events = np.copy(events)
        events = events[np.logical_and(events > data_range[0], events < data_range[1])]
    
    result = dual_annealing(total_log_likelyhood, bounds, args=(model, events), **kwargs)
    params = result.x

    return params

The annealing is required as opposed to minimize due to the non convex nature of the problem.

Your construction of the weight vector seems strange to me. Instead of a = np.hstack((a, 1 - np.sum(a))) should it not be a /= np.sum(a) to ensure that the weights sum to one?

In either case, unless you are trying to learn how mixture modelling works, I would use any of the battle hardened, optimised solvers available, in particular, if performance is important to you. Pomegranate is great.

@PaulBrodersen the parameters do not include all weights as that would overdefine the problem in parameter space. When I have 4 distributions I can only adjust 3 because they need to sum to one, so the paramter is not included.
I can avoid appending the array by manually adding the last one: np.sum(normal(x, mu[:-1], sigma[:-1], a)) + normal(x, mu[-1], sigma[-1], 1-np.sum(a)) but this does not fix the performance issues

I am working on a library for easy preliminary data analysis taylored to other students of physics and I want to include a model to generate when none is given. The minimizer is actually a bit more complex than presented here as it is the general solver I use for mle problems but this is functionally equivalent

I'm guessing that the main problem here is vectorize. I can most likely solve this by transposing and summing smartly but I'm still working on it

np.vectorize is just a glorified for loop and is usually slow.

the function normal is already vectorized. Just use it the way it is. Do not pass single values but rather pass arrays. eg a @ normal(x, mu, sigma) where a, x, mu, sigma are all arrays of the same length.

This does not work, because the x is of different length than the parameters. (I have more datapoints than dimensions in optimization space, kindof as a requirement to allow for fitting)

As suspected the primary problem was np.vectorize. By using np.transpose I can abuse the matrix multiplication to calculate the normal distribution element wise and sum appropriate axis of the array. The following is the optimized code:
def generate_gaussian_mix(n):

    """
    Dynamically generates a function for the superposition of `n` Gaussian functions.
    
    Args:
        n (int): Number of Gaussian functions to include in the superposition.
    
    Returns:
        function: A callable function `f(x, params)` where `params` is a flat array of weights, means, 
                  and standard deviations for each Gaussian component, of size 3*n.
    """

    def gaussian_mix(x, *params):
        
        if len(params) != 3 * n - 1:
            print(params)
            raise ValueError(f"Expected {3 * n - 1} parameters, but got {len(params)}.")

        params = np.asarray(params)
        mu = params[0::3]  # Means
        sigma = params[1::3]  # Standard deviations
        a = params[2::3]  # Weights

        return  np.sum(normal(np.transpose([x]), mu[:-1], sigma[:-1], a), axis = 1) + normal(np.transpose([x]), mu[-1], sigma[-1], 1-np.sum(a))[:,0]

    return gaussian_mix

